# MBA mid 2013 trackpad not clicking

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, trackpad

Should the top part of MBA mid 2013 (MD711) trackpad click? I recently noticed that mine doesn't. I don't know if it's an issue just with mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the trackpad is designed. The trackpad is pivoted at the top, so it requires more force to press at the top than at the bottom, up to the point where you are pressing at the pivot which won't click the trackpad.